# R: extract info from the data frame with row names

Tags: r

I want to extract specific information from the data frame, but can't extract row names too.

My dummy example:

```
dummy <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(34,11,9,32,23,13), ncol=2))
colnames(dummy) <- c('C1', 'C2')
rownames(dummy) <- c('Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3')

dummy
   C1 C2
Row1 34 32
Row2 11 23
Row3  9 13
```

I want to extract `C2` from the `dummy`. I tried:

```
dummy$C2
[1] 32 23 13

as.data.frame(dummy$C2)
  dummy$C2
1       32
2       23
3       13

subset(dummy)$C2
[1] 32 23 13
```

How can I extract row names too, for the result like this:

```
dummy_extracted

Row1       32
Row2       23
Row3       13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
dummy[, "C2", drop = FALSE]

     C2
Row1 32
Row2 23
Row3 13
```

Answer (score 1):

With ?subset()

```
 subset(dummy, select=C2)
      C2
 Row1 32
 Row2 23
 Row3 13
```

If you look at the documentation of ?subset(), by default:

```
 ## S3 method for class 'data.frame'
 subset(x, subset, select, drop = FALSE, ...)
```